# using regex and grepl to detect words starting with a specific pattern

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I do not understand why
`grepl("see*", "file SEC", ignore.case = TRUE)` returns `TRUE`?

I am trying to find all words that start with `see`, such as `See`, `seeing`, `seen`, etc. and remove them.
The string above "file SEC" does not have such a word, yet `TRUE` is returned.

Comment: You may have to use word boundaries if you have multi-words characters, as in my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use a word boundary (`\\b`)**

The pattern `"see*"` checks for "se" followed by any number of `"e"`s (`e*`)(including zero), so "SE" matches.

I believe you may want to look into something like this, without the "*"

```
grepl("^see", "file SEC", ignore.case = TRUE)

FALSE
```

In addition to the "^" sign, you can also include a word boundary `\\b`, so you can detect words that start with the pattern, but exclude those that do not, inside multi-word characters:

```
grepl("\\bSee", c("file SEC", "See", "seeing", "seen", "he was seen", "He did not forsee the event"), ignore.case = TRUE)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you!!! The last example is what I was looking for exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem as others have mentioned is that the question is specifying a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) rather than a [regular expression](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) or looked at in a different way it is specifying the wrong regular expression.

We can avoid both regular expressions and globs and only used fixed strings by using `startsWith` which tests whether a string starts with a fixed potential substring.  It does not support case insensitivity but we can use `tolower` to get that.

```
startsWith(tolower(c("file SEC", "seer", "a seer")), "see")
## [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

try grepl("^see", "file SEC")
the "^see" mean "all string that start with see"